# how do you parse this google maps JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using Google Places via:

https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/

```
var geocomp =  $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({types:['establishment', 'geocode']});
```

I get back the following JSON:

```
{
    "address_components": [
        {
            "long_name": "Empire State Building",
            "short_name": "Empire State Building",
            "types": [
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ]
        },
        {

        },
        …{

        }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "Empire State Building, 350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118, USA",
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 40.7484405,
            "lng": -73.98566440000002
        },
        "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport": {
            "south": 40.7470915197085,
            "west": -73.9870133802915,
            "north": 40.7497894802915,
            "east": -73.98431541970848
        }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJaXQRs6lZwokRY6EFpJnhNNE",
    "types": [
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
    ]
}
```

It returns the JSON data in the following callback:

```
$("#geocomplete")
  .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
}
```

I'm able to access elements of the address_components array as follows:

```
result.address_components[0].long_name
result.address_components[1].long_name
result.address_components[2].long_name
```

How do I access "lat" and "lng" in location.geometry?

I've tried

```
result.geometry.location.lat        
result.geometry.location.lng
```

and says lat contains:

```
function (){return a}
```

and lng contains:

```
function (){return b}
```

which makes no sense to me give the JSON included at the beginning.

How do i access those 2 values?

Comment: Can you share your snippet on jsbin.com?

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json good library to parse a json

Comment: @Azerty123, what wrong with `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Just call these functions to get `lat`/`long`: `result.geometry.location.lat()`

Comment: @Azerty123 We are in js here not .NET...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `location` is a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object. Anyway, you can access the coordinates using `result.geometry.location.lat()` and `result.geometry.location.lng()`.

Comment: you and vp_arth above are correct.  they are functions.  i got massively screwed up because based on the JSON i posted they were values.  i used JSON.stringify() to print the JSON, does that cause the lat() & lng() to be evaluated?

Comment: @user1126515 Yes, `JSON.stringify()` uses the value returned by the `toJSON()` function in the `LatLng` object. [More on `toJSON()` behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need: 
My example shows how to get data of a specific address but I think it will work.

**Classes:**

```
 public class GoogleGeoCodeResponse
    {

        public string status { get; set; }
        public results[] results { get; set; }
        public string error_message { get; set; }
        public string next_page_token { get; set; }

    }

    public class results
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string formatted_address { get; set; }
        public geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string[] types { get; set; }
        public address_component[] address_components { get; set; }
        public string vicinity { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public string international_phone_number { get; set; }
    }

    public class geometry
    {
        public string location_type { get; set; }
        public location location { get; set; }
    }

    public class location
    {
        public string lat { get; set; }
        public string lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class GooglePalceDetail
    {
        public results result { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string error_message { get; set; }

    }

    public class address_component
    {
        public string long_name { get; set; }
        public string short_name { get; set; }
        public string[] types { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
var address = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&key={1}", currentAddress, googleKey);

 string json = client.DownloadString(address);
 var gglGeo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleGeoCodeResponse>(json);

if ((gglGeo.status == "ZERO_RESULTS")){
 ViewBag.msg="no results";
 return View()
}
 var lat = gglGeo.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
 var lng = gglGeo.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
```